# how can i run the lstm_objection_detection code to train?

Tags: tensorflow-model-garden

i've read this code(https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/research/lstm_object_detection) but have no idea to run it,and how to make my custom dataset?i'm new and only use yolo ,now try to use net based on video

how to make my own dataset like imagenet VID?

Answer (score -1):

The LSTM object detection code you mentioned is a complex model and can be challenging to implement. You must have a good understanding of TensorFlow and object detection to successfully implement this model. However, the TensorFlow team has provided detailed instructions on how to run the code in the repository's README file.

Comment: @Mojtaba_Moghri can you edit your answer to include the link to the exact README file containing detailed instruction on how to run the lstm_object_detection. I'm in what I think is the repository and the README at the lstm_object_detection root does not contain instructions. Also looked in other sub directories.